# Подключение QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt

Я использую Qt Creator 7.0, Qt 5.15

Я подключаю в qmake `QT += webenginewidgets`, в хедере подключаю `#include <QWebEngineView> и` компилятор выдаёт:

> :-1: ошибка: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
> G:\study c++\Projkt Qt\04_Qt Test_3 Web\Web_Test\web_wedget.h:5: ошибка: 'QWebEngineView' file not found

Я проверяла, все библиотеки установлены.

Comment: Какой компилятор вы используете ?

Comment: И какую версию  Qt вы используете?

Comment: Я использую Qt Creator 7.0, Qt 5.15

Comment: А компилятор какой?

Comment: Я использую кроссплатформенную среду разработки Qt Creator 7.0.

Comment: Переформулирую вопрос, какой компилятор С++ вы используете?

Comment: Я поняла вас. Я использую Mingw-w64

Comment: Qt для mingw не содержит QWebengine, т.к. Chromium под mingw не собирается. Используйте компилятор msvc и сборку Qt под него, либо, если gcc вам больше нравится, установите linux (под wsl, как вариант).